# how to move router port 80 to other?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, webserver, port

I'm running a web server on my laptop but can't forward port 80 as my router doesn't allow me to (it seems). My router is a [TP-Link 300Mbps Wireless N ADSL2+ Modem Router Model No. TD-W8960N](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/cat-15_TD-W8960N.html).

I have tried some ideas but it's all in vain.

The error that is being displayed when I try to setup the redirect is "Since port 80 is used, the Modem Router WEB server port will be moved to 8080" (see also the below screenshot).
[image: this picture show the error caused during changing port to 80]

I need to setup the redirect for port 80, what else could I try?

Comment: http://www.tp-link.in/support-contact.html

Comment: The message you're seeing actually should indicate that the redirect is working, it should be telling you (from my understanding) that the default port 80 for the web interface will be moved to 8080.

Comment: no it didn't change it's to 80.it changed webserver port to 8080

Answer (score 4):

On my TP-Link router (different model), under **System Tools** -> **Manage Control**, the **Service Configuration** section controls router's management ports for internal access (using 192.168.0.1 from within my intranet) and external (using the router's public IP from the internet at large), and I assume yours will be similar:

[image: Router Management]

I assume that your error message meant that you have enabled external management and that its port number was changed, but I don't know if the internal port number was also modified. I recommend disabling remote management (as I have), as it is exposing an unnecessary vulnerability: changing your router's configuration when you are away is not something you are likely to want to do, since any mistakes could mess up your whole internal network, needing a physical reset.

As you see my external port was 80 (greyed), but because it is disabled I got no error message when setting up external port 80 for my web server. If your internal port was changed you can reset it here.

I don't know if your error message meant that the internal management port was changed as well as the external, but with my configuration I use port 80 on 192.168.0.1 (in your case 192.168.1.1) for internal router management, as I have always done, and the same port on both my internal web server address (in your case 192.168.1.110) and my router's public IP to access my web server.

After seeing your comment, I down-loaded your router's manual, and found in section 4.8.6.2 that remote management is controlled by this screen (make sure all the boxes are unchecked, unless you want Ping):

[image: Router Access]

I could not see any specific control over the router management port, so if it has changed on the intranet (though I see no reason that this need be so), then you'll need to use 192.168.1.1:8080 to connect to the router parameters. It won't affect the port used to access your web server: this will always be 80.

If the intranet management port has been changed and you really don't want this, then there are a couple of things to try:

1. Update to the latest firmware release: a newer version may have additional management settings.
2. If you investigate `telnet` management (this will be a non-trivial exercise), you'll find a very different text-based dialogue, but you will have access to different settings from those on the browser screen, and these *may* include the intranet management port.
3. If you restore factory defaults, then make sure that remote web access is disabled and then re-enter your web server port map, then you *might* not get the port 8080 change.

Before you try either of these, back up your current settings, so that you can quickly restore them if you don't get what you want, then learn to live with using 192.168.1.1:8080 for router management. After all, I presume it's not something you will do often.

Comment: i dont have the same options as you &  there is no option like external management

Comment: I didn't have the same options.. but it made me to think in different way... so I started checking all options in settings etc.. and finally found. "Access control, services control" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading it correctly, since you wanted port 80 to go to your INTERNAL Network (192.168.1.100:80), TP-Link needs to change its OWN WebServer (192.168.1.1) port to 8080 (to go into the TP-Link WebServer Admin page - the page you are seeing right now)

So in a way - you are done. You set up the correct port forwarding.

It just means when you need to access your TP-Link Admin Page, you open: 192.168.1.1:8080.

When you need to access your WebServer (running on your laptop) you put your connection WAN IP (whatever it is) and your TP-Link will forward the request to 192.168.1.100:80 (and I'm assuming this is your laptop).

Comment: you are right, how can i do do?

Comment: you are right, again but would you tell me how to change port no of router

Comment: Check your router manual. But by putting your router to do port forwarding to port 80 it is automatically changing it to port 8080. Unless you want to change your router port different (not 8080) then you are done. About how to change it - again check your manual.

Comment: ok i will check it

Comment: Did you find a solution?